# Deploying to Ubuntu Phone OS

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, ubuntu-sdk

I have set up the development kit using the command line options shown on the Go Mobile site and started QT Creator. Did the first tutorial and wanted to see it on my Ubuntu Phone Tablet but it could not find the device. Also QT Creator was V4 but I then updated with QT5 Creator. I can test the application on the Desktop but cant find a way to configure the device and the device tab don't exist.. you need to go into options to see it and nowhere can I see Ubuntu Device... Please help me to get the last thing set up. I am working on a few applications for the device and want to test on the Nexus 7.

Comment: Ubuntu Phones is in development, so it is off-topic here at Ask Ubuntu. We do not support Beta/Alpha/Development versions.

Comment: Okay I will. then please delete this question

Comment: I am still not clear when ubunt-touch questions are off-topic. There is a tag, Ubuntu is forwarding people to askubuntu and we are actively answering questions. I like askubuntu and I like ubuntu touch. I would be happy if both things can cooperate already...

Comment: I would suggest, to leave the question here till it's clear to the ubuntu touch community where this kind of question should be posted. Thanks.

Comment: ubuntu phone questions are ontopic here, I recommend editing your question to be more clear so we can get this question on the road to being answered.